# numpy installation error _build_utils.apple_accelerate

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, numpy, installation

I am trying to install a third part software with `ccmake` and I get an error when the software tries to download and install `numpy` (actually `numpy` is already installed, but I don't manage to pass this local installation to `cmake`).

`make` downloads automatically `numpy` from

https://pypi.python.org/packages/45/4e/03b577ffa5ca9b369cb75c79ca411e7449488eea2481665b819de0b5f2c4/numpy-1.13.0rc2.zip#md5=7a43a7fcc309a3d6a1829471dde053fd

then I get and error

```
import Error: _build_utils.apple_accelerate
```

I was searching on google and it looks like this is  an `apple` thing (?), but I am running `Linux CentOs 6.7`

this happens both with python/2.7.3 and python/2.7.13

EDIT:

this problem does not occur with python/2.7.8

Comment: Google, `numpy/_build_utils.apple_accelerate.py` → 1st hit → https://github.com/Mytherin/numpy-deferred/blob/master/numpy/_build_utils/apple_accelerate.py ...

Comment: @KnudLarsen I still don't understand why it fails. I remind you that the results from google are personalized

Comment: Add more details of what specifically you're doing. FYI you're supposed to build numpy via `setup.py`.